# Where am I going wrong in my routing logic?

Tags: cisco, routing

I was trying to ping the other router(ROUTER 2[192.168.4.1/30]) from ROUTER 1[192.168.4.5/30], 192.168.4.1. I even placed in a gateway of last resort with no success. Where am I going wrong with my routing logic?

ROUTE 1:

```
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.4.5 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
ip route 192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.4.1 
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.4.1 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

ROUTER 2:

```
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.4.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.5.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that you two different networks: `192.168.4.0/30` and `192.168.4.4/30`. To get from one network to another network, you need to go through a router. Router 1 has no idea where the `192.168.4.0/30` network is. Router 2 has no idea where the `192.168.4.4/30` network is.

You need to have a network in common between the two routers. That is why you use `/30` or `31` networks for point-to-point links. Each of those two network sizes has exactly two usable addresses, and you would assign one address each router on each end of the link.

Routers learn routes in three ways:

1. Directly connected networks
2. Statically configured routes
3. Dynamically from routing protocols

The flaw with your statically configured routes on Router 1 is that Router 1 has no idea where `192.168.4.1` is, or how to send traffic to it. Router 2 will also need to know how to get back to the Router 1 networks.

Comment: Silly me. For some reason my mind had the right idea but did not see that error like I should have. ;/

Comment: That is why a good peer review process is really essential for real networks. Don't blindly implement something without having someone else check it ahead of time. You employer would not be happy if is simple mistake brought down the network and cost the company millions of dollars.

Answer (score 0):

From the config. You can check next hop ip address 4.1 dosen't reachable from router 1 due to wrong subnet ip address configured if both router are point to point connected. Second reverse static route hasn't configured at router 2.

Answer (score 0):

As per Configuration provided , it is directly connected networks  no manually static route  Configuration is not required . When network is directly connected networks route is automatically creates in layer3 devices .

Moreover subnetmask used is 255.255.255.252 has only two usage ip address 192.168.4.1 &192.168.4.2 , ip address. 192.168.4.1 & 192.168.4.5 not comes under /30 subnets . Use /28 subnet for establishing connectivity.